# How to exclude commit messages from git log when printing changed files only?

Tags: git

I am trying to get a list of files that have changed on a branch since some date. This is what I have now:

```
git log --since="2022-10-13T17:40:05.232777" --name-only --pretty=format:'%f'
```

And that prints:

```
Even-more-test-files
python/tests_index/secondtestfile.txt
python/tests_index/teeeeeeeeeest.txt

More-test-files-for-git-log
python/findtest.py

Add-some-test-file
python/tests_index/testfile.txt
```

That's weird. The dash separated strings like `More-test-files-for-git-log` are commit messages, except for some reason spaces are replaced with dashes. What I want is just this:

```
python/tests_index/secondtestfile.txt
python/tests_index/teeeeeeeeeest.txt
python/findtest.py
python/tests_index/testfile.txt
```

No commit messages. No extra newlines. Just a list of files that have changed via a commit on this branch since the date I have given.

How to fix the `--pretty` argument so that I get what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> --pretty=format:'%f'
> ```
>
> The dash separated strings like `More-test-files-for-git-log` are commit messages, except for some reason spaces are replaced with dashes.

That's [what you asked for](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

> > ```
> > %f
> >     sanitized subject line, suitable for a filename
> > ```

> How to fix the `--pretty` argument so that I get what I want?

Use `--pretty=format:` (or `--format=`).

Comment: Nice. Thank you. Is there way to eliminate the dupes in the output? I can do that programmatically of course, but I am asking just in case you know.

Comment: Not with this particular command, but, if you know which commit is the *first* in the sequence and don't care if some file was changed and then changed *back*, run a diff against the parent of the first commit, and the final commit, with `--name-only`. Note that from Python you probably want to add `-z` and use the zero terminator, so that you can handle newlines in file names (rare as they should be).

Comment: Good point about the newlines. I think I don't need to worry about that now, but that is something that I'd end up debugging for hours at some point in my life if you didn't point it out. I guess in my case using `set` in python will be easier - otherwise I'd have to run multiple commands to get the first commit.